# How to fix the Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only in creating a scatter plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a scatter plot with data from FRED. Whenever I run the program, I get back the "Error: invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only".

```
fredsym <- c("UNRATE","JTSJOR")

for   (i in 1:length(fredsym)){
  getSymbols(fredsym[i],src="FRED")
}
```

Creating a dataframe for the UNRATE and JTSJOR

```
unemployment_diff <- diff(UNRATE)
unemployment_diff_bar.df = data.frame(date=time(unemployment_diff), coredata(unemployment_diff))

job_vacancy_diff <- diff(JTSJOR)
job_vacancy_diff_bar.df = data.frame(date=time(job_vacancy_diff), coredata(job_vacancy_diff))
```

Merging unemployment and job vacancy dataframes to a single dataframe

```
beveridge_curve <- merge(unemployment_diff_bar.df, job_vacancy_diff_bar.df, all=FALSE)
```

Plotting

```
scatter__plot <- ggplot(beveridge_curve, aes(x=UNRATE, y=JTSJOR))+ geom_point()+
  stat_cor(label.x=12, label.y=7)+
  labs(title = "Beverridge Curve", x = NULL,y = NULL, caption = "Source:BLS") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-500,1500), breaks=seq(-500,1500,200), labels = comma)+
  theme_bw()+
  theme (legend.title=element_blank(), legend.position = c(0.8, 0.9),
         axis.text.x = element_text(size = 14, angle = 45, hjust=1),
         axis.text.y = element_text(size = 14),
         axis.title = element_text(size = 14),
         plot.title = element_text(face="plain", size = 20, hjust=0.5, color="#3333B3FF"),
         panel.border = element_blank())+
  scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%Y-%m"), breaks='1 month')
```

Comment: Why are you trying to include date on the x axis if you are drawing a Beveridge curve? The x axis is unemployment rate, not date. Also, the values on the y axis range between -0.6 and +0.6, so you won't see any details with the y axis limits you have set

Answer (score 1):

This error occurred because you have not assigned a date column for the x axis. You are using `UNRATE` column for the x axis, which are not in date format

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to create dataframes for the plot. Simply merge unemployment_diff and job_vacancy_diff and remove the scale_x_date line.

This is because the Beveridge curve doe not need dates, only UNRATE and JTSJOR data values.

Comment: Recommend adding specifics for what code to remove/change and defining what the curve is that you are basing this on to help the OP -- if the curve is the vacancy rate (y-axis) plotted against the unemployment rate (x-axis), let em know.